# Why os.path.getsize() throw error in python?

Tags: python, os.path

I'm trying to print the size of all file lists, but it throws error.
Here is the code :

```
import os

def printSize(fileAbsPath) :
  print os.path.getsize(fileAbsPath)


for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk('/Users/kris/Desktop'):
  for filename in filenames :
    try :
      printSize(os.path.abspath(filename))
    except Exception as err:
      print 'An exception happend : ' + str(err)
```

And, the errors are :

```
An exception happend : [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/kris/Desktop/AutomateBoringStuff/.DS_Store'
An exception happend : [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/kris/Desktop/AutomateBoringStuff/.gitignore'
An exception happend : [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/kris/Desktop/AutomateBoringStuff/.gitmodules'
An exception happend : [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/kris/Desktop/AutomateBoringStuff/.localized'
.
.
.
.
An exception happend : [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/kris/Desktop/AutomateBoringStuff/BLE Scanner.m4a'
An exception happend : [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/kris/Desktop/AutomateBoringStuff/Screen Shot 2015-07-23 at 3.30.52 PM.png'
```

I don't know what's wrong with it. I thought it is kinda related with 'concealed files' but it wasn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
  printSize(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(folderName, filename)))
```

Comment: Great answer but it should be mentioned that there is no need to call abspath before calling getsize.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs of `os.walk` (emphasis added):

> Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames).
>   dirpath is a string, the path to the directory. dirnames is a list of the names of the subdirectories in dirpath (excluding '.' and '..'). filenames is a list of the names of the non-directory files in dirpath. Note that the names in the lists contain no path components. **To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in dirpath, do os.path.join(dirpath, name).**

I'm guessing you ran your script in `AutomateBoringStuff` (so it's the working directory), but the files are actually in `Desktop`.

`/Users/kris/Desktop/AutomateBoringStuff/BLE Scanner.m4a` should be `/Users/kris/Desktop/BLE Scanner.m4a`

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs.python](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/os.path.html)
os.path.getsize(path)
Return the size, in bytes, of path.

> Raise os.error if the file does not exist or is inaccessible

So catch this exception or make sure the file exists.